# Twitter upload status with media in android

Tags: android, twitter, media, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload media to twitter in android. I am using this [Update with Media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) Api. I am using the following code

```
multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    try
    {
        multiPartEntity.addPart("status", new StringBody("Metallica rules man! |m|"));
        multiPartEntity.addPart("media[]", new InputStreamBody(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.metallica), "metallica.jpg"));
        post = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");
        post.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        post.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
        consumer.sign(post);
        response = client.execute(post);
        entity = response.getEntity();
    } catch (Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get the [error code 131 - Internal error](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/making-api-responses-match-request-content-type) from Twitter. I also tried sending the image in the form of a byte array but in vain. I got the same error. Could anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Were you able to solr this?